# prevent repeat (Sch ID + App ID) to be in SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

The code of insert into

```
insert into app_eduBg
(
    ---school ID
    schoolID,
    -----applicant ID
    appID,
    studentID,

    stateID,
    countryID,

    age,
    startYear,
    startMonth,
    endYear,
    endMonth,

    finalGrade


)


SELECT 
---create 1, means Create primary school ID for it, can link with app_edu_school
1,
applicantID,
0,

0,
0,

coalesce(latestFormerSchAge,Null),
coalesce(latestFormerSchFromYear,Null),
coalesce(latestFormerSchFromMonth,Null),
coalesce(latestFormerSchToYear,Null),
coalesce(latestFormerSchToMonth,Null),
---create 11, means create primary 6 as there education background, can link with app_edulevel
11

from [app_AMaster(adv)] 
where Leaving !='Leaving'
```

**this is the image of [app_Amaster(adv)]**
[image: app_Amaster(adv)]

***Question:***

Actually I wish to insert into a list of  records table call "app_edubG" from "app_Amaster(adv)" where app_Amaster(adv) field is not 'Leaving' but the field must not repeat the same ('SchID'+"appID") but allow appID to be repeated?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent `schId`/`appId` from repeating, then define a unique constraint or index on those columns:

```
alter table app_eduBg add constraint unq_app_eduBg_schId_appId
    unique (schId, appId);
```

The database will then ensure that there are no duplicates.  An attempt to `insert` or `update` rows that would create duplicates will generate an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I found another way to prevent it to be repeated already.

Comment: @DesmondSim . . . Your method is not thread-safe; two jobs running at the same time could insert duplicates.  You should use the database mechanisms to ensure data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer already, by using this code it wouldn't repeat. I shouldn't hardcode as '1' to replace 'latestFormerSchID'. Thanks for giving some suggestion to me too.

```
insert into app_eduBg
(
    schoolID,
    appID,
    studentID,

    stateID,
    countryID,

    age,
    startYear,
    startMonth,
    endYear,
    endMonth,

    finalGrade


)


SELECT 
---create 1, means Create primary school ID for it, can link with app_edu_school
latestFormerSchID,
applicantID,
0,

0,
0,

coalesce(latestFormerSchAge,Null),
coalesce(latestFormerSchFromYear,Null),
coalesce(latestFormerSchFromMonth,Null),
coalesce(latestFormerSchToYear,Null),
coalesce(latestFormerSchToMonth,Null),
---create 11, means create primary 6 as there education background, can link with app_edulevel
11


from [app_AMaster(adv)] t1
Left Join app_eduBg t2 on t2.schoolID = t1.latestFormerSchID and t2.appID = t1.applicantID
where t2.appID is null and t1.latestFormerSchID is not null and Leaving != 'Leaving'
```